# Ratchet + Symfony 3.4 - Release memory

Tags: memory-leaks, doctrine-orm, ratchet, symfony-3.4, php-7.1

I'm trying to implement chat for my existing Symfony 3.4 app.

```
   $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                $this->chatManager
            )
        ),
        $this->webSocketPort
    );
    $server->run();
```

In my `chatManager` I'm accessing DB via DQL. First thing I found that Symfony can not detach entities by itself so I added

`$this->em->clear();`

in the end of each method where I did use entities.

Now, here is what I have in my `chatManager`

```
protected function sendMessage(ConnectionInterface $connection, $message): ConnectionInterface
{
    $context[] = 'chat';

    echo $this->getMemoryUsage() . PHP_EOL;

    return $connection->send(
        $this->serializer->serialize($message, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups($context))
    );
}

private function getMemoryUsage() {

    return sprintf('[Memory usage (currently) %dKB/ (max) %dKB]', round(memory_get_usage(true) / 1024), memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024);
}
```

I notice that memory do not release on it's own. It is just growing all the time until it reach some value, after that all requests I'm trying to do via websocket connection falling with error

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away`

What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Do you got already a solution for the memory leak ? Running into the same problem.

Comment: @SkaiBoa Hi! Well, after all I realized that the problem was not because of memory leak, but because of nginx connection timeout.

Comment: But you should also place `em->clear` everywhere you did use em

Comment: Thx for your answer. Additional to the clear method, I found out, that you can start the command with --no-debug even in the prod evironment reduces the memory compensation a lot.